# swiftui transition between two view

Tags: swiftui

I'm implementing a transition between this two view the login view and home view so when I press the login button the var vm.currentUserSignedIn (saved in app storage in the view model) goes to true and I expecting to make a transition on leave of the login view but I don't understand why I don't see it.

Here's the code:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var emailTextField: String = ""
    @State private var passwordTextField: String = ""
    @StateObject var vm: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack{
                NavigationView{
                    HomeView(vmLogin: vm)
                }
                
                ZStack{
                    if !vm.currentUserSignedIn {
                        loginView
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                    }
                    
                    if vm.isLoading {
                        Loading()
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(2.0)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with animation, like

```
    ZStack{
        if !vm.currentUserSignedIn {
            loginView
            .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
        }
        
        if vm.isLoading {
            Loading()
        }
    }
    .zIndex(2.0)
    .animation(.default, value: vm.currentUserSignedIn)  // << here !!
```